# Custom AlertViewDelegate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, delegates

I thought I did something clever, but its not quite working. The plan is to have a custom AlertViewDelegate object that implements the clickedButton method via a block.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AlertViewDelegate : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,copy) void(^completionBlock)(NSInteger clickedIndex, UIAlertView *alertView);

@end


#import "AlertViewDelegate.h"

@implementation AlertViewDelegate
@synthesize completionBlock;

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    completionBlock(buttonIndex,alertView);
}

@end
```

Then, in another class:

```
  AlertViewDelegate * del = [[AlertViewDelegate alloc] init];
    [del setCompletionBlock:^(NSInteger buttonIndex, UIAlertView *alertView) {
        NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex);
    }];

    UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"asdg" message:@"asdg" delegate:del cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"YES",@"NO", nil];
    [view show];
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when clicking the button. My guess is that the delegate was deallocated because I defined it inside a method (ie its not a property) -- is that a fair conclusion? Any suggestions on how to fix it without having to declare a alertviewdelegate property in each class where I use ie?

Comment: This problem has been explored before. One option is to make the alert view it's own delegate and store the blocks as associated objects, as was done in this project: https://github.com/MugunthKumar/UIKitCategoryAdditions (You could just use that code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - that is a fair conclusion. The problem is that the delegate is freed by ARC as soon as you leave the method you are in since it is only strong referenced in a local variable. For this to work you would need to keep a strong reference to the delegate object since UIAlertView will only keep a weak reference to the delegate.

Comment: Technically, it keeps an `unsafe_unretained` reference to the delegate. Otherwise it would fail silently rather than crashing.

Comment: Right. So I added a NSMutableArray *delegates to my view controller and just did [delegates addObject:(del)] when I created the delegate. And then [delegates removeObject:alertView.delegate] when it returned. Works like a gem! Any issues with that approach?

Comment: @JoshDG Conceptually, you are creating a retain cycle where: `VC -> AlertViewDelegate -> completionBlock -> VC`. This shouldn't be an issue since the alert view is pretty much guaranteed to break the cycle.